# Assign Google Fusion Tables Data to display Google Maps InfoBubble

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, infobubble

I am trying to create a map with data exported from my Google Fusion Tables. The problem is, I have so many data to be displayed including text and images. And I want to create info windows with tabs.

How will I be possibly display infobubble when I click on a marker? The code that I have now to retrieve Google Fusion Tables data is:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    query: {
        select: "col1",
        from: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    options: {
        styleId: 3,
        templateId: 3
    }
});
```

I already looked for ways to get this problem solved and I found this sample http://jsbin.com/efobeg/13/edit.

EDIT:

Here's the code that I am currently working on.

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'col7',
            from: '10NhYAiDivSpUnjvNsOwZVTEPV-RjhRGmyEOGjs4'
        },
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        options: {
            styleId: 2,
            templateId: 3
        }
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
        var name = e.row['restaurantname'].value;   
        var cuisine = e.row['cuisine'].value;
        var address = e.row['full_address'].value;
        var rating = e.row['rating'].value;
        if (rating != "") {
            if (rating == 1) {
                rating = "http://exrx.net/test_weewok2/1.png";
            } else if (rating == 2) {
                rating = "http://exrx.net/test_weewok2/2.png";
            } else if (rating == 3) {
                rating = "http://exrx.net/test_weewok2/3.png";
            } else if (rating == 4) {
                rating = "http://exrx.net/test_weewok2/4.png";
            } else {
                rating = "http://exrx.net/test_weewok2/5.png";
            }
        } else {
            rating = "http://exrx.net/test_weewok2/1.png";
        }

        var review = e.row['review'].value;
        if (review == "") {
            review = "No one has reviewed this place.";
        }
        var contentString = [
            '<div class="tabs">',
                '<ul>',
                    '<li><a href="#tab-1"><span>Overview</span></a></li>',
                    '<li><a href="#tab-2"><span>Review</span></a></li>',
                    '<li><a href="#tab-3"><span>Images</span></a></li>',
                '</ul>',
                '<div id="tab-1">',
                    '<b>' + name + '</b><img src="' + rating + '" /><br>',
                    '<font size=1><b>' + address + '</b></font></center>',
                    '<p align=justify><font size=1>' + cuisine + '</font>',
                    '</p>',
                '</div>',
                '<div id="tab-2">',
                    '<p align=justify><i>&quot;' + review + '&quot;</i></p>',
                '</div>',
                '<div id="tab-3">',
                    '<p>Images will be displayed here.</p>',
                '</div>',
            '</div>'
          ].join('');

          infowindow.setContent(contentString);
          infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
          infowindow.open(map);
          $(".tabs").tabs({ selected: 0 });
    });
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Map Screenshot]

Comment: What is wrong with using the example you found?  What problem are you having doing that with the data from your table?

Comment: @geocodezip http://jsbin.com/efobeg/13/edit This is giving an array of values to be plotted on the map. While my Google Fusion Tables returns its data through the code above. How will I do it?

Comment: Query your table either the Google Fusion Tables API v1.0 or if you have less than 500 rows, you can use a GViz Query.  How many rows does your table contain?  What does it look like?

Comment: @geocodezip, It has more than 1000 rows. It contains reviews of some places, images and long text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806713/adding-tabs-in-infowindows-googlemaps-api-google-fusion-tables-kml-import use an InfoBubble instead of an InfoWindow

Comment: @geocodezip I already tried using this `$(".tabs").tabs();` But the problem is there are really long reviews. I am only setting the tabs' height and width here. But when I use infobubble, it automatically adjusts to the content of the popup.

Comment: @geocodezip, I really need your help. I need to solve this.

Comment: You haven't provided enough context for me to answer your question.  You haven't provided the code for your attempt using tabs.  You haven't provided your code attempting to use InfoBubble.  you haven't provided the real ID for your FusionTable.  If you do some work (or at least reflect what you have done in your question), someone might be able to help.

Comment: @geocodezip, Please do see my edited question.

Comment: Assuming that works, did you try to convert it to a tabbed InfoBuble?

Comment: @geocodezip No, I have not yet tried converting this to an InfoBubble. But this one is working already.

Comment: [Sorry, the table you have requested does not exist](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1IKN6oxzGRRjlf9_3FgxIVrzODlNJ7qXW47Hxab8)

Comment: Same here, I find it hard to believe that code works for you.

Comment: @geocodezip Please see my edited question. I've got `tabs` to work now.

Comment: What is the problem, the code seems to work fine?